# Reload DOM except one element with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom

Ok, so I got an audioplayer on a page, which should not stop while navigating through the page.

The page layout is not changeable (requirement, not my idea), so it's not possible to just put the  with the audio player on the outside and reload the content.

Is it possible, to reload the DOM with ajax, but leave out the part with the audioplayer, to just replace everything around it?
As far as I've read this is not possible, but I want to make sure, since someone told me it is.

Thanks <3

Example of the Page

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerandnavigationetc">...</div>
<div id="content>
   <div id="breadcrumbsnstuff">...</div>
   <div id="leftcolumn">
       Content
   </div>
   <div id="rightcolumn">
       More content
       <div id="audioplayer">player</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    ...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend where in the DOM the audio player is. Potentially you could amend the DOM in a function before the AJAX is called so that everything to be changed is within a `<div id="ajaxme"></div>` and then the audio player is after it. On the "success" function of the AJAX call you could then do something like `$('#audioplayer').appendTo('#rightcolumn');`

So potentially the whole thing could be:

```
function ChangeDom() {
   $('body').html('<div id="ajaxme">' + $('body').html() + '</div>');
   $('#audioplayer').insertAfter('#ajaxme');

   // Do AJAX to replace ajaxme div

   $('#audioplayer').appendTo('#rightcolumn');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty much a hack, but I guess the only way is through hacks. Since rebuilding the homepage to a singlepage app would be quite a heavier task, but also better. Anyway thanks for this!